# How to get the value of str variable?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the URL (str variable) using FB API.

When I tried **CONSOLE2** `console.log(str)` it showed the exact value of **str** variable which contains URL for photo.

But when I tried **CONSOLE1** it didn't work. It printed nothing.

Is it because of some async functions? If yes, how can write the code that following two statements (**see Note 1**) work (it doesn't matter one executes after another, I just want the URL in **CONSOLE1** where I have called `getPhoto()`)

Note 1: Both statements mean the location.href and CONSOLE1, to ensure that I'm getting the value of **str** inside the `Login()` function.

```
  function Login()
  {         
    FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) 
       {
          getPhoto();
         // window.location.href="quiz.html";
          //**CONSOLE1** 
          console.log(str);
         } else 
        {
           console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
     },{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos,publish_actions'});
  }

  function getPhoto()
  {
    FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
      var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+=str;
         //**CONSOLE2**
         console.log(str);     
    });
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
function Login() {       
    FB.login((response) => {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            getPhoto((str) => {
                console.log(str);
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    },{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos,publish_actions'});
}

function getPhoto(callback) {
    FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', (response) => {
        const str = '<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src="' + response.data.url + '"/>';
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += str;
        callback(str);     
    });
}
```

There are other solutions too (for example, with Promises), but using a callback function is very easy. I also added ES6 syntax (const, arrow functions).

You can also use `FB.getLoginStatus` to check if the user is logged in on page load, and call `getPhoto` in the callback of that function too.

For example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: I quite didn't understand arrow thing. Could you please make it work without using arrow thing?

Comment: just replace this: "(response) => {" with this: "function (response) {" ...or better, learn ES6, it´s about time ;)

Comment: I tried to understand this callback thing by this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40842335/how-do-i-use-callback-to-access-this-variable but it didn't work. Could you please answer there so I can understand this thing?

Comment: if you don´t know what a callback function is, or what asynchronous means, you should learn the basics of javascript before dealing with the facebook api. those are free and pretty good, for example: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Comment: Thank you :) One more general question. I'm working with JavaScript since 1 year. I've used it in my practice projects. I've used it with jQuery and Ajax as well. I know about callbacks like callbacks in jQuery hide() or show() methods and especially callbacks like this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm The thing is I have worked with callbacks but still I don't understand the thing you have used and the example I've tried in above mentioned question. SO THE QUESTION IS: If someone asks me: Do you know JavaScript? How should I reply?

Comment: if you don´t know exactly how callbacks/async works, then you don´t know javascript, i´m afraid ;) tip: learn vanilla javascript, you really don´t need jquery and you should learn the basics before using any library.

Answer (score 0):

In the CONSOLE2 block, you explicitly define the variable str:

```
var str=...
```

But in CONSOLE1 block, you never actually define the variable. When the function **getPhoto** terminates, the variable **str** goes out of scope and no longer exists.

To fix it, put your logic inside the callback function on the **FB.api** call. You can place that call inside the FB.login callback function rather than in its own function. Like this:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
...
```

In javascript, you have to chain or nest your callbacks. You have to wait for the login callback, then make the next API call, then make your get picture callback, etc.

Comment: putting FB.api inside the FB.login callback instead of a separate function is not a good idea, what if you want to call that function again later, or on page load?

Comment: If you actually DO want to do that you can always refactor. No point in making things more complicated when the guy asking the question doesn't understand scoping. Returning a value from another function requires a callback. I gave him the simplest possible answer.

Comment: Specifically, look at his comments on the other answer: "I quite didn't understand arrow thing. Could you please make it work without using arrow thing?" I felt the answer I gave was commensurate with his understanding of JS and specifically addressed his problem.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of str var remains inside the getPhoto function. For getting value in CONSOLE1 you need to do return value of str from getPhoto function.

Hope this helps you.