# How do I use callback to access this variable?

Tags: javascript

I've called `myFunc` inside `myFunc2`. Now what I want is to print `var2` when I call `myFunc2` using *callback* concept. I know something is wrong. The code I've tried isn't working.

It is showing this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: newfunc is not defined(…)

How can I fix it?

CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function myFunc(parameter){
            var var2="another thing";
            newfunc(var2);
        }
        function myFunc2(){
            var var1="Something";
            myFunc(newfunc(some));
            console.log(var1);
            console.log(var2);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunc2()">BUTTON</button>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

According to comments, I didn't defien `newfunc()`. Now I've defined it. But it's not working.

```
<script>

        function myFunc2(){
            var var1="Something";
            myFunc(function newfunc(some){
                console.log(var2);
            });
            console.log(var1);
        }
        function myFunc(parameter){
            var var2="another thing";
            newfunc(var2);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: what about `newfunc`? also in myFunc2 declaration, the `some` is not initialized, this is another problem.

Comment: And where is your newfunc()?

Comment: This is what I don't understand. I know the code is wrong. I tried this example to understand this thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838085/how-to-get-the-value-of-str-variable ( luschn's answer)

Comment: If you pass `myFunc(newfunc);` then you need to define newfunc and then you need to call `parameter(var2)` in myfunc

Comment: I just want to print var2 using myFunc2()

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: @VikasKumar I have tried to make my answer little descriptive but I strongly suggest you to refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o

Answer (score 0):

This is the way it works:

```
  var a = function myFunc(parameter){
                var var2="another thing";
                parameter.call();
          }

    a(function(){console.log("the function parameter")})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not that sure what you are trying to achieve. Is it something like this?

```js
 var var2;
 function myFunc(parameter){
    var2="another thing";
    return var2;
 }
 function myFunc2(){
     var var1="Something";
     myFunc(var1);
     console.log(var1);
     console.log(var2);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunc2()">BUTTON</button>
```

You can check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/e4ag774p/)

Answer (score 0):

Function cannot share variable defined in their individual scope but they can share their values using `arguments` and `return` value. This is how 2 function talk.

Also remember, when you add `()` after a function name, it is called immediately. If you need to pass callback, you will have to pass reference (`functionName`).

You can refer following post: [Passing parameters to a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458553/javascript-passing-parameters-to-a-callback-function) for more information.

```js
function newfunc(str){
  return "The test String is: " + str;
}

function myFunc(callback) {
  var var2 = "another thing";
  // return value
  return callback(var2);
}

function myFunc2() {
  var var1 = "Something";
  // Accept value that is returned and save it in local variable
  // Also adding "()" after function name will call it and pass its return value as argument.
  // If you even need to pass reference of a function with callback, use `.bind(context, args)`
  var var2 = myFunc(newfunc);
  console.log(var1);
  console.log(var2);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunc2()">BUTTON</button>
```

#### Snippet 2 explanation

First, defining function inside `()` will make it an expression and its reference will not be preserved. Due to this, your function is still not accessible.

Second, when you pass a function as a callback, it reference is shared and is available by argument name. In your case `parameter`. So instead of `newfunc(var2)` do `parameter(var2)`

Third, `var2` does not exists inside `newfunc`. You are sharing value using argument (`some`). Use this to log.

```js
function myFunc2() {
  var var1 = "Something";
  // Here newfunc will be ddestroyed after the call as it is wrapped inside ()
  myFunc(function newfunc(some) {
    console.log(some);
  });
  console.log(var1);
}

function myFunc(parameter) {
  var var2 = "another thing";
  parameter(var2);
}

myFunc2();
```